# Managing activities in android game

Tags: android, android-activity, view

Creating a game on android.
I have a Game activity with custom view Graphics.
I want to lunch GameOver activity when character dies, but application crashes 
(on the line: startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.GAMEOVER")).

I tried to create method gameOver() and start activity in it.

```
    public class Game extends Activity {

        static Graphics graphics;
        //...

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            graphics = new Graphics(this);
            setContentView(graphics);
            //...

            }
        //  TODO 
            void gameOver() {

        // Game crashes here
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.GAMEOVER"));
            }
    }
```

Then I tried to run this method from my custom view by creating Game object:-

```
public class Graphics extends View {
    Game game;
    private boolean somethingHappened;
    //...

    public Graphics(Context context) {
            super(context);
            game = new Game();
      }
            @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (somethingHappened) {
            theHeroDies();
        }

        invalidate();
    }
    void theHeroDies() {
        game.gameOver();
    }
   }
```

GameOver activity perfectly works if I run by with a menu button.

Manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.emi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Game"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GAME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".GameOverActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GAMEOVER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The log is here:

```
05-10 12:33:13.619: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:13.621: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:13.779: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:13.781: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:13.800: I/View(31179): Touch down dispatch to com.example.emi.Graphics{423dc3c8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,960}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=301.44177, y[0]=450.5307, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=291289301, downTime=291289301, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
05-10 12:33:13.985: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:13.987: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.001: I/View(31179): Touch up dispatch to com.example.emi.Graphics{423dc3c8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,960}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=301.44177, y[0]=450.5307, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=291289389, downTime=291289301, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
05-10 12:33:14.192: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.193: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.209: I/View(31179): Touch down dispatch to com.example.emi.Graphics{423dc3c8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,960}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=296.45102, y[0]=407.57544, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=291289614, downTime=291289614, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
05-10 12:33:14.227: I/View(31179): Touch up dispatch to com.example.emi.Graphics{423dc3c8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,960}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=296.45102, y[0]=407.57544, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=291289692, downTime=291289614, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
05-10 12:33:14.392: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.394: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.552: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.553: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.711: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.713: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.866: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:14.867: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.030: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.031: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.173: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.176: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.345: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.348: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.525: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.527: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.712: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.715: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.907: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:15.910: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.090: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.095: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.256: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.258: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.431: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.434: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.601: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.604: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.774: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.777: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.958: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:16.961: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.126: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.129: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.292: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.295: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.470: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.473: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.657: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.659: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.828: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:17.831: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.021: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.023: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.191: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.196: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.371: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.374: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.543: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.548: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.730: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.733: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.943: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:18.946: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.124: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.127: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.293: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.296: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.467: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.470: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.650: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.653: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.820: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.823: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.990: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:19.993: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.168: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.171: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.339: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.343: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.526: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.529: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.695: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.697: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.880: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:20.882: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.058: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.061: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.239: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.241: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.433: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.435: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.611: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.614: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.788: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.790: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.968: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:21.971: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.150: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.153: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.340: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.344: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.523: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.526: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.711: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.714: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.880: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:22.882: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.073: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.076: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.257: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.260: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.350: D/dalvikvm(31179): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3097K (5748), 17% free 16475K/19616K, paused 36ms, total 50ms
05-10 12:33:23.500: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.504: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.672: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.676: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.851: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:23.854: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.621: D/View(31179): [ANR Warning]onDraw time too long, this =com.example.emi.Graphics{423dc3c8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,960}time =746
05-10 12:33:24.622: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.625: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.766: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.768: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.930: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:24.933: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.080: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.083: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.252: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.255: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.411: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.414: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.568: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.571: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.739: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.742: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.892: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:33:25.895: D/OpenGLRenderer(31179): finish <0x61ced4a0>
05-10 12:34:22.685: D/AndroidRuntime(31179): Shutting down VM
05-10 12:34:22.685: W/dalvikvm(31179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d2ecf8)
05-10 12:34:22.686: W/dalvikvm(31179): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
05-10 12:34:22.688: W/System.err(31179): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 12:34:22.700: W/System.err(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3483)
05-10 12:34:22.703: W/System.err(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3435)
05-10 12:34:22.708: W/System.err(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3686)
05-10 12:34:22.714: W/System.err(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3654)
05-10 12:34:22.715: W/System.err(31179):    at com.example.emi.Game.gameOver(Game.java:53)
05-10 12:34:22.717: W/System.err(31179):    at com.example.emi.Graphics.die(Graphics.java:515)
05-10 12:34:22.719: W/System.err(31179):    at com.example.emi.Graphics.onDraw(Graphics.java:289)
05-10 12:34:22.720: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14728)
05-10 12:34:22.722: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13588)
05-10 12:34:22.724: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.725: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.727: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.729: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.730: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.732: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.734: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.735: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.737: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.739: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.741: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1627)
05-10 12:34:22.742: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1506)
05-10 12:34:22.745: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2722)
05-10 12:34:22.751: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2587)
05-10 12:34:22.758: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
05-10 12:34:22.760: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
05-10 12:34:22.761: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
05-10 12:34:22.763: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
05-10 12:34:22.770: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
05-10 12:34:22.772: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
05-10 12:34:22.774: W/System.err(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
05-10 12:34:22.776: W/System.err(31179):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-10 12:34:22.779: W/System.err(31179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-10 12:34:22.781: W/System.err(31179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-10 12:34:22.782: W/System.err(31179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
05-10 12:34:22.783: W/System.err(31179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 12:34:22.785: W/System.err(31179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-10 12:34:22.786: W/System.err(31179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
05-10 12:34:22.787: W/System.err(31179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
05-10 12:34:22.789: W/System.err(31179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 12:34:22.789: W/dalvikvm(31179): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179): Process: com.example.emi, PID: 31179
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3483)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3435)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3686)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3654)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at com.example.emi.Game.gameOver(Game.java:53)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at com.example.emi.Graphics.die(Graphics.java:515)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at com.example.emi.Graphics.onDraw(Graphics.java:289)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14728)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13588)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1627)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1506)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2722)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2587)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
05-10 12:34:22.832: E/AndroidRuntime(31179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add stacktrace and be more specific, what exactly is not working. And why do you set your methods protected?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `invalidate()` in `onDraw()` is almost surely wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with invalidate()? Actually it works fine

Comment: Sebastian Walla, you are right, it's no need to use protected

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `invalidate()`, here. `invalidate()` means *request draw*. `onDraw()` is then called when your view is drawn. That is, usually *after* it has been invalided already. You are requesting a re-invalidate directly after your view has just been drawn, hence my questioning the usefulness of that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start the activity from the View using the Context.

You could try changing this:

```
void theHeroDies() {
    game.gameOver();
}
```

to this:

```
void theHeroDies() {
    getContext().startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.GAMEOVER"));
}
```